# How to delete a row from table using SPSS Modeler

Tags: jython, spss-modeler

I'm using SPSS Modeler 17.0 and I want to delete a row from a table. In export database node there is only the option `Delete all existing records`. It deletes all the records and does enable to delete just one using a `WHERE` sql like condition.

Is there any other way to do it? using jython scripts for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this from a database source node, which is a little counter-intuitive.
In the node, just select the `SQL Query` mode in the `Data` tab and enter the SQL statement(s) required to delete records that you wish to remove.
You can then either just hit the `Preview` button to execute the statement(s) or you may attach any executable node to the source node and execute that.